# Discover services using avahi in AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, mdns, avahi

I have a separate VPC and subnet with ec2 instances running in them. I have installed avahi on one of the instances for discovering all the services in that subnet. But avahi is not able to discover this services which are running on other instances. I have tried running `avahi-browse -art` for discovery but getting no result. I have checked the connectivity between the instances with ping and it is good.

So any possible solutions to resolve this?